# Embedding Crystal Reports in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I'm new to Crystal Reports and Visual Studio. I already created reports in crystal reports and I also have a Report Viewer in my forms in Visual Studio 2010. I am wondering how to embed the created reports in the report viewer in visual studio 2010 forms and what references should I include in order for it not to have errors. Please help. Thanks